# Hide content of parent element without hiding children in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="parent">
    Hello world
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</span>
```

Rules of the game:

- I want to remove the "Hello world" string using CSS
- The `<a>` tags should still be visible
- I cannot touch the HTML code
- No javascript

So the solution would be like setting `display:none` on a `<span>` element surrounding the "Hello world" string only. The problem is that there is no such `<span>` and I cannot create one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`display:none;` always hides children and overrides their `display` properties.

You can try using `visibility` instead:

```
.parent { visibility: hidden;}
.parent a { visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: This actually seems to work, even though it's totally unexpected behaviour in my opinion

Comment: That can't work, because the a-element is still inside a parent element that is not displayed. Visibility only keeps the used place of the hidden element open.

Comment: @Sven Bieder: it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/AJKeM/
allthough the 'Hello World' part still takes up some space
(tested in Chrome & Firefox). But like I said, it's completely unexpected behaviour

Comment: Yup, you'd need to offset the container if you didn't want the empty space. It works for me in FF, Chrome and IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/n5uya/

Comment: @jfrej: with offset you mean some absolute offset? Or is there a better approach that works independently of the width of the span content? Your answer is great, only need to get rid of the empty space now.

Comment: To offset you could set the anchors to display block and use some negative margin.

Comment: OK, I have researched it and it seems to be the wanted behavior. The expected behavior of visibility is to hide the element, but the hidden element still influences the layout and is in the document flow. All children elements are also hidden, as long as not manually set to visible. Good catch I would have never tried that.

Comment: To answer my own question, this will do the trick of removing the whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/AJKeM/2/

Comment: @p-mesotten nice one with the `float` - you can add `margin-left` to add space between anchors. Just updated my fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/n5uya/

Comment: @ReinderWit that's the problem that it takes up space. I want to make current element to be a parent of its grandparent or great grandparent.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. That is like you have a flag in your hand and you expect that when you sit in a closed box, someone can still see the flag in your hand. The only way you can achieve that aim is to take the children out of the parent and attach them somewhere else. And that would be dom-manipulation (javascript).

EDIT:
After deeper researches of the technical definition of the visibility property and the wanted behavior I have figured out, that this answer is not correct.
**jfrej** has given the correct answer.

Comment: +1 for the closed box analogy. To make your analogy withstand the accepted answer, you could consider the box to be transparent instead of gone when visibility is set to hidden (instead of the box to be completely gone when display is set to none).